# Create NSViewController with error Swift

Tags: nsviewcontroller

When i try to create a customs viewcontroller using xib in swift with NSViewController and i have this error, what is it?

> [image]

Comment: this question should specify (either within the question or in a tag) whether were doing this for macOS or iOS... NSViewController is for macOS, UIViewController is for iOS

Answer (score 0):

Is the target set to macOS? It's saying it can't find the Cocoa framework, which happens if the target build is other than macOS. If you have defaulted to an iOS build, you will get this error